# making 1 factor from 2 factors in R

Tags: r

hello i have 2 csv files with names of persons, i save it each one with a read.csv() instruction, they look like this

```
    > x2[1:10]
 [1] JUAN CARLOSRODRIGUEZHERNANDEZ   DANIEL EUGENIOURQUIETAGUTIERREZ
 [3] FERNANDOLOPEZGARCIA             EDGAR IVANHERNANDEZJUAREZ      
 [5] JUAN RAFAELXTIBURCIO            GERARDORANGELAGUAYO            
 [7] EUCARIORANGELRAMIREZ            JUAN DANIEL SANCHEZZUÑIGA      
 [9] MARIANOTELLEZAGUIÑAGA           DIEGO ARMANDOROMERORAMIREZ     
109771 Levels:   ABIGAILNAVARROAMBRIZ ... ZURIELVILLEGASMATA
```

the other is like this one but with other names, i want to ask u how can i "merge" both list into one, i would like that the new list put the first entry of x2 after the last of x1 in order to make just one big list of names =3 in advance, thank u so much

Comment: srry bro that one does not helpme the merge(x1,x2), i get this error > l <- merge(x1,x2)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 149.0 Gb

Comment: convert from factors to characters, join, then convert to factor.

Comment: im making this chachimouchacha, do i join them with merge?

Comment: x1 = as.vector(x1); x2 = as.vector(x2); x3 = c(x1,x2)

Comment: thank u so muuuuuuch! i was like "oh i supose i must create a zero vector with dim = dim(x1+x2) and set every element of the x1 on the blablalbalba, u save me a lot of time thank u so much!